# Prolog checking the database

Tags: prolog

Is it possible to go through the database and check if any form of Predicate(Atom) exists by using the preicate isInData(Predicate,Atom)?

Comment: You can call a predicate and its arguments using `call(Predicate, Atom)`. If it fails, you know it's not in the database. So that would be `is_in_data(Predicate, Atom) :- call(Predicate, Atom).`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ISO standard `current_predicate/1` predicate, which checks/returns *predicate indicators*, i.e. terms of the form `Functor/Arity`.

There's also a de facto standard `predicate_property/2` predicate that allows you to query the properties of a predicate given its calling template.

If you want to check not only predicates, by their clauses, you can use the ISO standard `clause/2` predicate.

Given that you're using SWI-Prolog, to lookup the documentation for these predicates, got to its website and type their predicate indicators in the search box in the top-right corner.

Comment: Your question is a bit ambiguous. But lurker's comment is likely the solution you're looking for unless you want to examine the database predicates *without* querying them. If that's the case, then you will likely need to use the reflection predicates I enumerated.